# Ошибки при компиляции программы, выполняющей инициализацию OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

На основе первой статьи NeHe, написал программу, инициализирующую OpenGL окно. Скомпилировал, выдала несколько ошибок. Вот они:

> `1>opengl32.lib : warning LNK4003: недопустимый формат библиотеки; библиотека пропущена`
> `1>opengl32.lib : warning LNK4003: недопустимый формат библиотеки; библиотека пропущена`
> `1>init.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp__glLoadIdentity@0 в функции "void __cdecl ReSizeGLScene(int,int)" (?ReSizeGLScene@@YAXHH@Z)`
> `1>init.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp__glMatrixMode@4 в функции "void __cdecl ReSizeGLScene(int,int)" (?ReSizeGLScene@@YAXHH@Z)`
> `1>init.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp__glViewport@16 в функции "void __cdecl ReSizeGLScene(int,int)" (?ReSizeGLScene@@YAXHH@Z)`
> `1>init.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp__glHint@8 в функции "int __cdecl InitGL(void)" (?InitGL@@YAHXZ)`
> `1>init.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp__glDepthFunc@4 в функции "int __cdecl InitGL(void)" (?InitGL@@YAHXZ)`
> `1>init.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp__glEnable@4 в функции "int __cdecl InitGL(void)" (?InitGL@@YAHXZ)`
> `1>init.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp__glClearDepth@8 в функции "int __cdecl InitGL(void)" (?InitGL@@YAHXZ)`
> `1>init.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp__glClearColor@16 в функции "int __cdecl InitGL(void)" (?InitGL@@YAHXZ)`
> `1>init.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp__glShadeModel@4 в функции "int __cdecl InitGL(void)" (?InitGL@@YAHXZ)`
> `1>init.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp__glClear@4 в функции "int __cdecl DrawGLScene(void)" (?DrawGLScene@@YAHXZ)`
> `1>init.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp__wglMakeCurrent@8 в функции "int __cdecl CreateGLWindow(wchar_t const *,int,int,int,bool)" (?CreateGLWindow@@YAHPB_WHHH_N@Z)`
> `1>init.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp__wglCreateContext@4 в функции "int __cdecl CreateGLWindow(wchar_t const *,int,int,int,bool)" (?CreateGLWindow@@YAHPB_WHHH_N@Z)`
> `1>D:\OpenGL\1\Debug\1.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 12 неразрешенных внешних элементов`

В чем они? Что не так.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include "gl\gl.h"
#include "gl\glu.h"
#include "gl\glaux.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "opengl32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "GLaux.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "GLu32.lib")

HGLRC hRC = NULL;
HDC hDC = NULL;
HWND hWnd = NULL;
HINSTANCE hInstance;

bool keys[256];
bool active = true;
bool fullscreen = true;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc( HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM );

// Функция, для изменнеия размеров окна
GLvoid ReSizeGLScene( GLsizei width, GLsizei height )
{
    if(height == 0 ) height = 1;

    glViewport( 0, 0, width, height );
    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();

    gluPerspective( 45.0f, (GLfloat)width / (GLfloat)height, 0.1f, 100.0f );

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();
}

// Установка параметров OpenGL
int InitGL( GLvoid )
{
    glShadeModel( GL_SMOOTH );  // Плавное цветовое сглаживание

    glClearColor( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ); // Окраска в черный цвет

    glClearDepth( 1.0f );   // Разрешить очистку буфера глубины
    glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );  // Разрешить тест глубины
    glDepthFunc( GL_LEQUAL );   // Тип теста глубины

    glHint( GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST );    // Улучщение перспективы

    return true;
}

// Основная часть - прорисовка
int DrawGLScene( GLvoid )
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
    glLoadIdentity();
    return true;
}

BOOL CreateGLWindow( LPCWSTR title, int width, int height, int bits, bool fullscreenflag )
{
    GLuint PixelFormat;
    WNDCLASS wc;

    DWORD dwExStyle;
    DWORD dwStyle;

    RECT WindowRect;
    WindowRect.left = (long) 0;
    WindowRect.right = (long) width;
    WindowRect.top = (long) 0;
    WindowRect.bottom = (long) height;

    fullscreen = fullscreenflag;

    hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC) WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = NULL;
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = (LPCWSTR)"OpenGL";

    RegisterClass(&wc);

    if( fullscreen )    // Полноэкранный режим?
    {

        DEVMODE dmScreenSettings;
        memset( &dmScreenSettings, 0, sizeof( dmScreenSettings ) );
        dmScreenSettings.dmSize = sizeof( dmScreenSettings );
        dmScreenSettings.dmPelsWidth = width;
        dmScreenSettings.dmPelsHeight = height;
        dmScreenSettings.dmBitsPerPel = bits;
        dmScreenSettings.dmFields = DM_BITSPERPEL | DM_PELSWIDTH | DM_PELSHEIGHT;

        if( ChangeDisplaySettings( &dmScreenSettings, CDS_FULLSCREEN ) !=
            DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL )
        {
            if( MessageBox( NULL, (LPCWSTR)"The Requested Fullscreen Mode Is Not Supported By\nYour Video Card. Use Windowed Mode Instead?", 
                                (LPCWSTR)"NeHe GL", MB_YESNO | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION) == IDYES )
                fullscreen = false;
            else
            {
                MessageBox( NULL, (LPCWSTR)"Program Will Now Close.", 
                                    (LPCWSTR)"ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONSTOP );
                 return false;          
            }
        }
    }

    if( fullscreen )    // Мы остались в полноэкранном режиме?
    {
        dwExStyle = WS_EX_APPWINDOW;
        dwStyle = WS_POPUP;
        ShowCursor( false );
    }
    else
    {
        dwExStyle  =   WS_EX_APPWINDOW | WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE;    
        dwStyle    =   WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW;     
    }

    AdjustWindowRectEx( &WindowRect, dwStyle, false, dwExStyle );

    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(  dwExStyle, (LPCWSTR)("OpenGL"), title,            
          WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | dwStyle,          
          0, 0, WindowRect.right-WindowRect.left,   
                WindowRect.bottom-WindowRect.top,    
          NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL );

    static  PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd=            // pfd сообщает Windows каким будет вывод на экран каждого пикселя
    {
        sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),            // Размер дескриптора данного формата пикселей
        1,                  // Номер версии
        PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW |              // Формат для Окна
        PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL |              // Формат для OpenGL
        PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER,              // Формат для двойного буфера
        PFD_TYPE_RGBA,                // Требуется RGBA формат
        bits,                  // Выбирается бит глубины цвета
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,              // Игнорирование цветовых битов
        0,                  // Нет буфера прозрачности
        0,                  // Сдвиговый бит игнорируется
        0,                  // Нет буфера накопления
        0, 0, 0, 0,                // Биты накопления игнорируются
        32,                  // 32 битный Z-буфер (буфер глубины)
        0,                  // Нет буфера трафарета
        0,                  // Нет вспомогательных буферов
        PFD_MAIN_PLANE,                // Главный слой рисования
        0,                  // Зарезервировано
        0, 0, 0                  // Маски слоя игнорируются
    };

    PixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat( hDC, &pfd );
    SetPixelFormat( hDC, PixelFormat, &pfd );
    hRC = wglCreateContext( hDC );
    wglMakeCurrent( hDC, hRC );

    ShowWindow( hWnd, SW_SHOW );       // Показать окно
    SetForegroundWindow( hWnd );      // Слегка повысим приоритет
    SetFocus( hWnd );                // Установить фокус клавиатуры на наше окно
    ReSizeGLScene( width, height );     // Настроим перспективу для нашего OpenGL экрана.

    InitGL();

    return true;

}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc( HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)          
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_ACTIVATE:   // Проверка активности окна
            {
                if( !HIWORD( wParam) )  active = true;
                else    active = false;

                return 0;
            }

        case WM_SYSCOMMAND: // Перехватываем системную команду
            {
                switch( wParam )
                {
                    case SC_SCREENSAVE:
                    case SC_MONITORPOWER:
                    return 0;
                }
                break;
            }

        case WM_CLOSE:  // Мы получили сообщение о закрытии
            {
                PostQuitMessage( 0 );
                return 0;
            }

        case WM_KEYDOWN:    // Была ли нажата кнопка?
            {
                keys[wParam] = true;
                return 0;
            }

        case WM_SIZE:
            {
                ReSizeGLScene( LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam));
                return 0;
            }

        return DefWindowProc( hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam );
    }
}

int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hIntance,
                    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                    int nCmdShow )  {
    MSG msg;
    BOOL done = false;

    if( MessageBox( NULL, (LPCWSTR)"Хотите ли Вы запустить приложение в полноэкранном режиме?",  
                          (LPCWSTR)"Запустить в полноэкранном режиме?", 
                          MB_YESNO | MB_ICONQUESTION) == IDNO )
        fullscreen = false;          // Оконный режим
    CreateGLWindow( (LPCWSTR)"NeHe OpenGL окно", 1024, 768, 32, fullscreen);
    while(!done)
    {
        if( PeekMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE ) )
        {
            if( msg.message = WM_QUIT) done = true;
            else {
                TranslateMessage( &msg );
                DispatchMessage( &msg );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if( active )
            {
                if( keys[VK_ESCAPE] ) done = true;
                else {
                    DrawGLScene();
                    SwapBuffers( hDC );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return ( msg.wParam );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже, что твоя IDE не может найти или открыть файл opengl32.lib,
напиши в google.ru "скачать opengl32.lib", как скачаешь, то копируй в папку 
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib (если ты ипользуешь MS Visual C++).